# Python JSON data into HTML table

Tags: python, html, api

I'm pretty lost. Not going to lie. I'm trying to figure out how to parse JSON data from the college scorecard API into an HTML file. I used Python to store the JSON data in a dictionary, but other than that, I'm pretty dang lost. How would you write an example sending this data to an HTML file?

```
def main():
    url = 'https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json'
    payload = {
        'api_key': "api_key_string",
        '_fields': ','.join([
            'school.name',
            'school.school_url',
            'school.city',
            'school.state',
            'school.zip',
            '2015.student.size',
        ]),
        'school.operating': '1',
        '2015.academics.program_available.assoc_or_bachelors': 'true',
        '2015.student.size__range': '1..',
        'school.degrees_awarded.predominant__range': '1..3',
        'school.degrees_awarded.highest__range': '2..4',
        'id': '240444',
    }
    data = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
    for result in data['results']:
        print result

main()
```

Output:

```
{u'school.city': u'Madison', u'school.school_url': u'www.wisc.edu', u
'school.zip': u'53706-1380', u'2015.student.size': 29579, u'school.st
ate': u'WI', u'school.name': u'University of Wisconsin-Madison'}
```

Edit: For clarification, I need to insert the return data to an HTML file that formats and removes data styling and places it onto a table.

Edit II: Json2html edit

```
data = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
for result in data['results']:
    print result

    data_processed = json.loads(data)
    formatted_table = json2html.convert(json = data_processed)

    index= open("index.html","w")
    index.write(formatted_table)
    index.close()
```

Edit: Json2html output:

[Output image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9rIW.png)

Comment: You say "send this data to a HTML file". Thats quite an ambiguous question. Do you have a server that is serving the HTML files? Do you simply want to insert the returned data in a HTML file that neatly formats and removes the data type styling and places it into a table for example? Basically, can you be more specific and or expand on "put the data in a HTML file" please?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I need to insert the return data to an HTML file that formats and removes data styling and places it onto a table. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thanks. The other guy beat me to the answer. *tips hat*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`json2html`](https://pypi.org/project/json2html/) module! This will convert the JSON that was returned into a 'human readable HTML Table representation'.

This code will take your JSON output and create the HTML:

```
data_processed = json.loads(data)
formatted_table = json2html.convert(json = data_processed)
```

Then to save it as HTML you can do this:

```
your_file= open("filename","w")
your_file.write(formatted_table)
your_file.close()
```

Comment: Hey thanks Jen. I'll give it a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Actually, what do you think about using Pandas instead of json2html?

Comment: You can use Pandas to create a table but you cannot directly input that into an HTML file. To turn a Pandas data frame into an HTML table you can use DataFrame.to_html().

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. I did "DataFrame.to_html()" and while everything printed out on the VM, I didn't get any input on an HTML file.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the code that you tried and I will take a look?

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, I did that. :)

Comment: `data = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
formatted_table = json2html.convert(json = data_processed)
index= open("index.html","w")
index.write(formatted_table)
index.close()` Let me know if this works. Is there a reason why you were looping through the JSON output?

Comment: Hey Jen, I got "global name 'data_processed' is not defined'. Also, I was looping through the JSON output so I can get a list of fields I inserted into the payload variable.

Comment: Nevermind! I just changed 'data_processed' to 'data' and it works. It doesn't look human friendly, unfortunately. I gotta find a way to fix that. :)

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: I'll post the output above. However, I've submitted my project on GitHub. If you've got the time, I'd be happy to hear any other suggestions you may have regarding parsing data from the college scorecard API to the HTML file. Url here: https://github.com/10asmock/school-year-data/blob/master/test.py

Comment: Posted the output as an image file.

Comment: No pressure but if this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. If you feel like I did not completely answer your question no worries :)

Comment: It worked just fine, Jen! Thank you so much for your help!